# Multiplecolumns populate row access

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a scenario as follows:

```
 Column 1:Midterm 1 Score      Grade      Column2:Midterm 2 Score      Grade:
     Good                      99           Okay                        75
     Very Good                 98           Great                       99
     Great                     100          Good                        80
```

Is it possible to create a table (using a query), where these records would be listed in one list vertically example:

```
    Midterm Scores                        Midterm Grade
    Good                                        99
    Very Good                                   98
    Great                                       100
    Okay                                        75
    Great                                       99
    Good                                        80
```

If it is possible how would I do this?
Thanks

Comment: How your table looks like?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, currently table 1 looks like the first scenario and I'm just trying to flatten it sort of speak to get to the second scenario.

Comment: This is very possible but I second the question what your table structure looks like. Do you really have 2 fields called `Grade` and `Grade:`  ?

Comment: show your tabel schema

Comment: @Matty It is impossible that you have two colums with same name in one table also table names with blank is not ggod practice

Comment: @Jens I don't actually have these column names, but the structure of my table is similar. I used this as an example. I have a form which populates a table. this form updates 3 new courses (course names) and 3 different scores. The form is set up that each new skill, fills a column. hence this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is really a table design issue. What you should do is recreate your table in a more normalized way. Simple example:

```
MidtermScores:

ID            AutoNumber    PK
MidtermNumber Number
Description   Text
Grade         Number
```

Then you could simply query the table

```
SELECT Description, Grade
FROM MidtermScores;
```

Or

```
SELECT "Midterm" & [MidtermNumber], Description, Grade
FROM MidtermScores;
```

Lastly for completeness, this answers your original question but is a bad route to take:

```
SELECT MidtermScores.Midterm 1 Score AS Midterm Scores, MidtermScores.Grade AS Midterm Grade
FROM MidtermScores
UNION ALL
SELECT MidtermScores.Midterm 2 Score AS Midterm Scores, MidtermScores.[Grade:] AS Midterm Grade
FROM MidtermScores
```